# Angular 2 - Two Services, second requires result of first

Tags: service, angular, promise, chaining

I guess I need some type of promise chain, but the syntax eludes me...

Within the same component:

I'm calling:

```
this.somethingService.getSomethings().then(somethings => this.somethings = somethings);
```

Then I need to call:

```
this.otherService.getOthers(this.somethings).then(others => this.others = others);
```

In the second service call I'm using the result of the first to perform aggregate functions on its content, but its empty when the second call is made, thus the second service returns empty.

How can I get the second service to wait until the first promise has been resolved.

Thanx

Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain promises this way:

```
this.somethingService.getSomethings().then(somethings => {
  this.somethings = somethings;
  return this.otherService.getOthers(somethings);
}).then(others => {
  this.others = others;
});
```

The second callback will receive the result of the promise returns by the first callback.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, this doesn't error out - but this.somethings is empty???

Comment: Oups. There was a typo in my answer: `somethings` instead of `this.somethings`. I updated it...

Comment: OK Better, Service two is now returning calculated values, however my view is empty due to a *ngIf="somethings.length > 0" - it still thinks its an empty array.

Comment: Great! So add this in the first callback: `this.somethings = somethings;`. I updated my answer...